# How to trigger event based trigger for blob storage in Azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-trigger

I am trying to trigger azure blob storage from logic app but, I don't see any event based option. There is option for frequency. Is there any way to create event based trigger for blob storage in logic apps.

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `When a resource event occurs` trigger taking *Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts* as Resource Type. So that you can make logic app trigger using certain event types.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[When a resource event occurs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureeventgrid/#triggers)

Comment: If I go with resource event, how would I will be able to pick the files that are added to blob in next step.

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari Just to clarify that there are no 2 things such as files or blobs in the Blob Storage the files inside Blob Storage are called blobs. If you want your logic app to get triggered when blob is added then you can either use Azure storage's `When a blob is added or modified` or Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated in event type item.